# running a javascript code within an <iframe> that have been received from submitting a from in the page itself

Tags: php, javascript, forms, iframe

this is the form:

```
<form id="aqarinfo" action="newEntry.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target0">

<inputs>

</form>
```

the iframe:

```
 <iframe id="upload_target0" name="upload_target0" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

the `newEntry.php` page:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 window.top.window.success_upload(<?php echo "\"".$lastAqar . "\""; ?>);
 </script>
```

the javascript function in the parent page:

```
 function success_upload(lastaqar){
  do things....
 }
```

unfortunately the JavaScript function does not get called. what would be the issue here?

Comment: Try using "window.parent.success_upload"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
parent.success_upload(<?php echo "\"".$lastAqar . "\""; ?>);
</script>
```